# Certain central extensions of simply connected simple algebraic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-k-theory

An offbeat question involving Milnor's $K_2$ has come up recently.  Start with an algebraically closed field $F$ (perhaps required to be of characteristic 0).  Let $G$ be a connected, simply connected simple algebraic group over $F$, for instance $\mathrm{SL}_n(F)$, maybe of rank $\neq 1,2$ to be on the safe side.  Then consider a linear group $H \subset \mathrm{GL}(V)$ with $V$ finite dimensional over $F$, together with an epimorphism $\pi:H \rightarrow G$ of abstract groups whose kernel lies in the center of $H$. (EDIT: Further assume that $H$ is equal to its derived group.  I neglected to include this crucial condition in the question originally posed to me.)

> Are these conditions enough to imply that $\pi$ has trivial kernel?

Note that when $G$ is a special linear group of rank at least 2, its abstract universal central extension is the *Steinberg group* (with generators and relations specified by Matsumoto) and the kernel of the resulting map is $K_2(F)$.   Typically this is an infinite group, uncountable if $F$ is uncountable (Milnor).  However, if we add the assumption that $H$ acts *irreducibly* on $V$, then by Schur's Lemma $\pi$ induces a sort of reverse projective representation of $G$ with image equal to the image of $H$ in $\mathrm{PGL}(V)$.  Older work of Steinberg would allow us to lift this projective representation to an ordinary one, thus mapping $G$ onto $H$.   (See sections 6,7 of Steinberg's Yale lectures [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~rst).)

However, it's apparently undesirable in the original question to make any assumption about complete reducibility of the action of $H$.  So I'm unsure what can be said, given only that $H$ is a linear group.

Comment: What is to prevent us from taking $H= Z \times G$ where $Z$ is an Abelian linear algebraic group over $F$?

Comment: @Aakumadula: Quite right. I left out one crucial part of the original question, that $H$ should be perfect (equal to its derived group). (This assumption is the abstract version of "connected" in the setting of central extensions.)

Comment: Would it be stupid to hope all this is controlled by $H^2(G,F)$ and $H^1(G,F)$? Which are trivial, even in positive characteristic ... That book of Serre's where he thinks about extensions of algebraic groups comes to mind.

Comment: Is it too optimistic to expect that every linear representation of a perfect central extension $H$ of $G$ is trivial on the kernel of $H\to G$?

Comment: Yes, it is too optimistic: $H$ has by definition a faithful linear representation. If you wish to prove that the kernel is trivial, it is equivalent to your statement.

Comment: I mean: (unlike in the OP's question): let $H$ be a perfect central extension of $G$ ($G$ being as in the question), is every linear rep of $H$ trivial on the kernel $Z$ of $H\to G$? The OP's question seems equivalent to whether every linear rep of $G$ is *unipotent* in restriction to $Z$ for every such $H$.

Comment: So I think this won't work for positive characteristic. If we let $G=SL_p(F)$ with char $F=p$ then as abstract groups $G$ is also isomorphic to $PGL_p(F)$. So there is a (non-algebraic) map from $H=GL_p(F)$ to $G$ with non-trivial kernel being the centre of $H$. Does that make sense?

Comment: @David: $H$ is not a perfect group.

Comment: @Yves Of course...